# Dynamically creation of promises and running sequentially

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sequential

I'm running into the following problem.

I have the following promise (simplified):

```
module.exports.checkVotes = (groupId) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
     // some db stuff onoing
     ...
     .then((votes)=>{return resolve(votes}})
     .catch((err)=>{return reject(err}})
    })
}
```

At some point I'm looping through an object. For each entry i have to call promise above. But before the 2. Promise starts, the first one have to be finished...and so on.
I tried this, but as soon as I call the promise it gets executed.

```
 .then(()=>{
      for (let i=0;i<groups.length;i++){
           // for each group I want to call the promise later
           //but it executes as soon as I push it.
           tasklist.push(this.checkVotes(groups[i])) 
       }

       return tasklist.reduce((promiseChain, currentTask) => {
           return promiseChain.then(chainResults =>
               currentTask.then(currentResult =>
                    [ ...chainResults, currentResult ]
                )
           );
        }, Promise.resolve([])).then(arrayOfResults => {
                console.log(arrayOfResults)
            }).catch((err) =>{console.log(err)});
         })
  })
```

I can not run this with Promise.all() because for some database things, I need this to run sequentially. Moreover I can not hardcode this because the number of groups is variable.

How can I solve this?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) in `checkVotes`!

Comment: Where did you find that `reduce` solution? When using that approach, `taskList` is expected to be an array of promise-returning *functions* ("tasks"), not an array of promises.

Comment: What nodejs version do you use? Can you use `async`/`await`?

Comment: yes can use asnyc and await

Comment: I don't see any problems why you wouldn't use Promise.all as it is right now. Your database requests will start sequentially either way upon checkVotes() invocation. Promise.all is just a nice wrapper to handle all your requests resolution.

Comment: checkVotes internally creates some transactions and I guess blocks some table rows, there I retrieve a pool connections timeout if I'm using Promise.all

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was with putting promises in the `taskList`, not tasks (functions that return promises). The idea behind making them run in sequence is to *call* them in the `then` callback in the `reduce`:

```
return groups.reduce((promiseChain, currentGroup) => {
    return promiseChain.then(chainResults =>
        this.checkVotes(currentGroup).then(currentResult => [...chainResults, currentResult])
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    );
}, Promise.resolve([]))
```

But if you can use `async`/`await` syntax, you don't need to do all of this anyway and can write the much simpler and more efficient

```
const results = [];
for (const group of groups)
    results.push(await this.checkVotes(group));
```

Answer (score 0):

seems to work like this:

```
groupIds = [12, 45, 34];
return groupIds .reduce((promise, groupId) => {
                return promise.then(() => {
                    return this.checkVotes(groupId)
                        .then((votes)=>{
                            votesList[groupId] = votes
                        })
                        .catch((err)=>{
                            throw err
                        })
                })
            }, Promise.resolve())
```